# Remove json attribute in php

Tags: php, html, json

I have json and I want to remove 1st attribute from it but don't know how.
Here is my json:

```
["car",["Nissan","Chevrolet","Ford"]]
```

I want to show it like this:

```
["Nissan","Chevrolet","Ford"]
```

my Php

```
$url = 'http://example.com/json?=car';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
echo $content;
```

Comment: not really an "attribute"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert it into an array first, point it to that particular index you want then encode again. (Assuming that json string on your question is really the exact json string you have).

```
$contents = '["car",["Nissan","Chevrolet","Ford"]]';
$data = json_decode($contents, true);
$contents = json_encode($data[1]);
echo $contents; // ["Nissan","Chevrolet","Ford"]
```

Comment: I am getting this error Warning: reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: @osisboris try my revision, are you sure thats your only json? or a part of it?

Comment: answer null. it is same as I showed above just value changes

Comment: Hi it is working fine. It was the typo $content , $contents . Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to just extract array.

```
json_decode($content[1])
```

Comment: If you need still JSON string, not an array — you need @Ghost answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents($url)); //converts json data to array

echo $json_array[1]; //displays ["Nissan","Chevrolet","Ford"]

//contents of json_array
 /* Array
  (
    [0] => car
    [1] => Array
      (
        [0] => Nissan
        [1] => Chevrolet
        [2] => Ford
    )

  ) */
```